# On reboot command router resets Openwrt Caos Calmer 15.05

Tags: networking, openwrt

I m using tplink wr841n v11 and made bin(CC-15.05) file for it using source code, but the issue is I m running 1 script, which downloads file and edits chilli file and then I wrote reboot after all happens. After reboot everything changes to default router(like router is reset to default) and when I comment to reboot command, then it changes in files, but then I manually reboots router it automatically resets, all the settings like ssid, lan ip, pppoe settings etc. changes to default one. Plz, help me in this situation
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and thanks for ur response amine ahd, I got my answer and I found what was the problem. Basically, I had made own luci and there was to many files in /www/cg-bin/ there was no space left and thats why after any command from my gui or manually it works and edit also but when u reboots, it resets router. After deleting files from cgi-bin folder and build again, now it works superb. At a time of building openwrt I gave permission to /etc/ to 777, so no issues for read only file system.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/filesystems), /etc is read only and so cannot be modified. What you need to do is create a partition in /overlay which should be writable and save your configuration there and then have a script copy your config to /etc during boot time.