# Openwrt Hostname is not permanent

Tags: hostname, openwrt

I am using /etc/config/system file to change the hostname of the openwrt/lede router and after restart using "/etc/init.d/system restart" the name changed successfully. when I reboot the router, the name got changing to "lede", and also my entry in system not available. What is the actual issue here and How to solve this?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your file system does not support persistent write-back to flash storage? Do all files get reset after a reboot? Does the entire `/etc/config/system` file get reset, or is it just just the hostname line that is reverted? Do you use any GUI or automatic tools to make configurations? A clean OpenWrt/LEDE installation does not write to any file in `/etc/config/`.

Also see: [On reboot command router resets Openwrt Caos Calmer 15.05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689880/on-reboot-command-router-resets-openwrt-caos-calmer-15-05?rq=1) for more information about problems with persistent write-back, which is most likely your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is some default configs in /etc/config/system file. when i add some more,  file is getting reverted. But other files in /etc/config/ not having this issue. And I tried to add a name through LUCI gui. That also didnt work after reboot/Poweroff